# using c# to access shibboleth session data

Tags: c#, iis-6, shibboleth

I have successfully installed Shibboleth SP on our server (server 2003 IIS6) and it is working with a third party IDP.  I know this is working as the /Session value returns the attributes I need.

At the moment though I am unable to access those session variables from a .net application.  the variables are not being put in the head.

Any help greatly appreciated.

--Update--
In the attribute-map.xml I have the following related to the attribute I need (affiliation)

```
<Attribute name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:eduPersonScopedAffiliation" id="affiliation" aliases="Shib-EP-Affiliation">
    <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="ScopedAttributeDecoder" caseSensitive="false"/>
</Attribute>
<Attribute name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.9" id="affiliation" aliases="Shib-EP-Affiliation">
    <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="ScopedAttributeDecoder" caseSensitive="false"/>
</Attribute>
```

Is ther something extra I should be adding into here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall, the attributes should be available in the `Request.ServerVariables` collection or the `Request.Headers` with the keys you specify in your Attribute-Map.xml configuration. Be aware though that there is some [documented strangeness with the keys when using IIS and ASP.NET](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/secadv_20090615) wherein they tend to get a prefix prepended to the names you've configured and some other things that occur, too. The most reliable approach to finding out what the actual key values are is to knock up a test page that iterates through the contents of the `ServerVariables` or `Headers` collection and displays them.

Comment: I have looked in both of those collections and do not see a shibboleth related variable :(.  I have added abit about the attibute-map.xml above.

Comment: The Shibboleth config itself is somewhat out-of-scope of the original question since you asked how to access the attributes in an asp.net app. However, I can say that from experience it is very easy to get Shibboleth config wrong and the problem may even lie elsewhere than the Attibute-Map.xml file. I'd advise you to turn on the most verbose level of logging in shibd.logger, restart the daemon and look in the log to see what attributes are arriving and being mapped when you authenticate and are redirected. The Shibboleth Google group would be the best place for config questions, though.

Comment: I had my config wired up wrong so it was working but not where I was expecting it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the IIS to proxy the Shibb headers to your application - see description here: https://spaces.ais.ucla.edu/display/iamucla/InstallShibSPOnWindowsIIS

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and eventually found the issue in my `shibboleth2.xml`.

In my `<Host>` element I was missing the `authType="shibboleth"` attribute.  My application was able to decode SAML requests and I could see my attributes at `/Shibboleth.sso/Session`, but the attributes weren't populating the environment variables or headers.  Once I added the `authType` attribute, everything fell into place.

Also, it was very helpful to create an `.aspx` page containing just

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" Trace="true" %>
```

while hunting for the Shibboleth attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar issue and it turned out that my `<Host>` element in the `shibboleth2.xml` file was specifying a path that was not valid for where I was testing. If I visited a url under the path, the headers were accessible.

Updating the 'path' attribute to a valid path for the site resolved this for me.